# Pass PHP Class as Parameter

Tags: php, class, parameters, byref

How can i pass a class as a parameter in my function

So far i've tried

> ```
> $sc = new SampleClass();
> SampleFunction($sc);
>
>
> function SampleFunction(&$refClass)
> {
>     echo $refClass->getValue();
> }
> ```

this is a simplified example of what im doing.. i actually have to do complex procedures inside this sample function. I'm not getting any response from the sample function. What am i doing wrong? thank you

**UPDATE**

> char.php

```
   class Charss {
    var $name=0;
    var $hp=500;
    var $spd=10;
    var $rtime=10;
    var $dmg=10;

    function __construct( $name, $hp, $spd, $rtime , $dmg) { 
            $this->name = $name;
            $this->hp = $hp;
            $this->spd  = $spd;
            $this->rtime = $rtime;
            $this->dmg = $dmg;
        }

    function get_name() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    function set_name($new_name) {
        $this->name = $new_name;
    }

    function get_hp() {
        return $this->hp;
    }

    function set_hp($new_hp) {
        $this->hp = $new_hp;
    }

    function get_spd() {
        return $this->spd;
    }

    function set_spd($new_spd) {
        $this->spd = $new_spd;
    }

    function get_rtime() {
        return $this->rtime;
    }

    function set_rtime($new_rtime) {
        $this->rtime = $new_rtime;
    }

    function get_dmg() {
        return $this->get_dmg;
    }

    function set_dmg($new_dmg) {
        $this->dmg = $new_dmg;
    }
}
```

> myclass.php

```
    require("char.php");
class Person {

function try_process()
{
    $chr1 = new Charss("Player1",500,3,0,50);
    $chr2 = new Charss("Player2",500,6,0,70);

    while ($chr1->get_hp() > 0 && $chr2->get_hp() > 0)
    {
        $sth = min($chr1->get_rtime(), $chr2->get_rtime());
        if ($chr1->get_rtime() == 0 && $chr2->get_rtime() > 0)
        {
            exit;
            Fight($chr1,$chr2);
            $chr1->set_rtime($chr1->get_spd());
        }
        elseif ($chr2->get_rtime() == 0 && $chr1->get_rtime() > 0)
        {
            Fight($chr2,$chr1);
            $chr2->set_rtime($chr2->get_spd());
        }
        else 
        {
            Fight($chr1,$chr2); #having trouble with this
            $chr1->set_rtime($chr1->get_spd());
        }
        $chr1->set_rtime($chr1->get_rtime() - $sth);
        $chr2->set_rtime($chr2->get_rtime() - $sth);
    }
}

function Fight($atk,$def)
{
    $def->set_hp($def->get_hp() - $atk->get_dmg());
    echo $atk->get_name() . " attacked " . $def->get_name() . " for " . $atk->get_dmg() . " damage";
}
```

}

so im calling the function try_process on button click

Comment: If your update is now complete, your problem is that you can't simply call `Fight($atk,$def)`, but rather need to call it in the form `$this->Fight($atk,$def)`, as it's a member of the class.

Comment: Also, you were using the property `$get_dmg` (instead of `$dmg`) in `Charss::get_dmg()`, which didn't exist.  I edited the code to use `$this`, and the property that does exist, and it now runs for me.  :)

Comment: I found this hoping to figure out how to pass a _class_ not an _instance of a class_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're actually doing there is passing an object, not a class.

```
$sc = new SampleClass();
```

creates an instance of SampleClass, aka an object.

I assume there's some error being thrown elsewhere as what you have is correct.
I tested the following code and got the expected output:

```
class SampleClass
{
    public function getValue()
    {
        return 4;
    }
}

$sc = new SampleClass();
SampleFunction($sc);

function SampleFunction(&$refClass)
{
    echo $refClass->getValue();
}
```

Output: 4

If you provide more details of your actual code we might be able to determine the problem.

Comment: ive posted some codes.. i was just trying some concepts on php that is why im doing this.. these are the practice codes im working with

Comment: i was lacking $this i should call my function $this->SampleFunction(&$refClass) since i was using required on my pages

Answer (score 1):

I can't see anything wrong with your code

using &$refClass is however is not recommended and I guess willbe removed from future iteration of PHP version

but here is an example

class objects are passed as reference I suppose so no need of '&'

http://ideone.com/GbmUy

Answer (score 0):

Why is the function argument a reference? Probably shouldn't be.

Other than that, there's nothing wrong with you posted, so the error is likely within `SampleClass`.

Comment: i need it as reference as i have to do changes to the Property Members of the class within that function. is it possible?

Comment: It is passed as a reference by default.  The & isn't required.

Answer (score 0):

Others have answered pretty well, but this is a silly little example to show you how to modify the class (either by calling a property setter, or setting public properties directly)

```
class foo {
    private $member1;
    public  $member2;

    public function __construct($member1,$member2) {
            $this->member1=$member1;
            $this->member2=$member2;
    }

    public function SetMember1($value) {
            $this->member1 = $value;
    }
    public function GetMember1() {
            return $this->member1;
    }
}

function SetMembers(foo $obj, $member1, $member2) {
    // Call a setter
    $obj->SetMember1($member1);

    // Set a member variable directly
    $obj->member2 = $member2;
}

$obj = new foo('default member 1', 'default member 2');

echo "member1 (before): {$obj->GetMember1()}\n";
echo "member2 (before): {$obj->member2}\n";

// Change values
SetMembers($obj, 'new member1', 'new member2');

echo "member1 (after): {$obj->GetMember1()}\n";
echo "member2 (after): {$obj->member2}\n";
```

This will output:

```
member1 (before): default member 1
member2 (before): default member 2
member1 (after): new member1
member2 (after): new member2
```

Comment: hi actually have those already i think.. im concerned about passing a parameter which the parameter is a class